# Detailed stats for vehicles, MAX's, and their weapons?

Tags: planetside-2

To start,  [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0AuOojvNLMApVdEtIU1NKenEzNzZOSWNaanFqSUVxLWc&type=view&gid=12)  is a great resource, but it only has information about infantry. I've checked, a few times.

What brings me to ask this is, specifically, the MAX suit slot upgrade that provides "additional small-arms fire resistance" ranging from 1-5%. This seems like a horribly ineffective way to spend certification points, especially when compared to your other options (auto-repair and 5-25% explosive resist). HOWEVER, if the MAX already has some bullet resistance, that 5% could suddenly jump to a huge value (80% base +5% equals out to effectively 25% reduction in damage taken).

I'm also curious about tanks and planes, and their guns/resistance values/etc. How much more effective are AP vs. HEAT when fighting tanks? What kind of damage multiplier do you get for hitting the back? That sort of thing. Is there a resource that can give me this kind of information?

Comment: I know that rear damage inflicted on a tank is 240% stronger than the front or sides (although the vanguard has 10% resistance to frontal damage)

Comment: Until someone analyzes the code I doubt we can get real stats, sorry. I'm interested to know as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer; however, I have managed to dig up solid information about the tanks [here](http://forum.symthic.com/planetside-2/3959-tank-damage-and-analyses/). I still have very little information regarding MAX's, beyond [this chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Amnj8jnZLDIOdEx6azNNdVozRmxLVkI2WnZmS2NqV1E&output=html) which details their anti-infantry weapons.

To expand on this answer I've found relevant information about tanks. Tanks actually take (default) 50% damage on top and sides, 45% on the front (38% for Vanguards), and 120% to the rear. The armor plating defensive items add onto this, so for example the 5% damage resistance on frontal plating reduces damage to 40% (roughly twice as good as it says on the box). In all cases this results in an increase to the hits-to-kill of one (or two for prowlers, more for Lightning 75mm gun)

Comment: Saying you receive, for example, a 5% increase is really misleading considering the actual benefits you reap. SOE needs to provide clearer descriptions of the benefits.